# Cannot connect to local MySQL database with React Native using Redux

Tags: reactjs, laravel, database, redux, connection

```js
export const GET_JOB_POSTS = "GET_JOB_POSTS";

const apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs"

export const getJobs = () => {
  try {
    return async dispatch => {
      const result = await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      });
      const json = await result.json();
      if (json) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_JOB_POSTS,
          payload: json
        })
      } else {
        console.log("unable to fetch")
      }
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

On this function I get the following this error

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: Network request failed
> TypeError: Network request failed

It works fine when on postman, the response I get from postman is

```json
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Game Developer",
        "description": "Build Games",
        "salary": "50000.00",
        "company": "Laravel",
        "created_at": "2023-10-26T04:19:03.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-10-26T04:19:03.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Solidity Engineer",
        "description": "blockchain",
        "salary": "50000.00",
        "company": "LG",
        "created_at": "2023-10-26T04:19:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-10-26T04:19:47.000000Z"
    }
]
```

It's very weird. I tried changing `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/jobs"` to my own network `"http://192.168.1.30:8000/api/jobs"` but I still getting the same issue. The API was built with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in the middle of the `try` branch. Rewrite the asynchronous action to contain an atomic `try/catch` pairing that surrounds the asynchronous code that possibly throws errors or rejects Promises.

```js
export const getJobs = () => {
  return async dispatch => {  
    try {
      const result = await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      });

      const json = await result.json();

      if (json) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_JOB_POSTS,
          payload: json
        });
      } else {
        console.log("unable to fetch");
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```